# Populate a thread-safe Set concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

Assuming I have a thread-safe collection, for which I would populate in the following manner:

```
   Set set = new HashSet();
   for (Map map : maps) {
        set.addAll(doSomeExpensiveProcessing(map.keySet()));
    }
```

What would be the best way of performing this concurrently? (ie each map would concurrently add its keys to the set.

EDIT - I'm aware HashSet is not thread-safe, but that would be outside the scope of the question, as far I'm concerned.

EDIT2 - It was correctly pointed that for this particular scenario concurrency will not reap huge benefits, but there will be additional steps, which I've now included in the code example.

Comment: What is the focus of the question? Making it parallel or making concurrent accesses safe? For the second, you could add the `volatile` modifier to your `set` variable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: @CedricReichenbach the focus would be to make it parallel.

Comment: I don't understand this question.  "best" in what way?  The hard thing here is the concurrency.   Are the maps large or something?

Comment: To elaborate on what *Gray* said: if you're expecting to gain some performance benefit from parallel calls to `addAll()`, it's unlikely: when a thread is accessing the `Set` it will block all other threads, and since this is a CPU-bound operation it will essentially make it sequential (and in reality, may be much slower due to the extra steps required to resolve contention).

Comment: @parsifal : I understand that know, and possibly the question was not well written. There will be additional processing of the Maps which (hopefully) will benefit from the concurrent processing. The general question should have been "How to turn a loop into a set of concurrent operations".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @OldCurmudgeon has a nice basic approach, in more serious code you probably want to make a `Callable` that does the expensive processing of the keys, and returns a new `Collection`.  That can be combined with an Executor and/or a CompletionService.  You don't even need a concurrent collection at the end.

e.g., if the keys are Strings

```
public class DoesExpensiveProcessing implements Callable<Set<String>> {

   final Set<String> inKeys;

   public DoesExpensiveProcessing(Set<String> keys) {
     this.inKeys = keys;  // make a defensive copy if required...
   }

   public Set<String> call() {
      // do expensive processing on inKeys and returns a Set of Strings
   }
}
```

At this point you don't even need a parallel collection

```
List<DoesExpensiveProcessing> doInParallel = new ArrayList<DoesExpensiveProcessing>();
for (Map map : maps) {
   doInParallel.add(new DoesExpensiveProcessing(map.keySet()));
}

Set theResultingSet = new HashSet<String>();
List<Future<Set<String>>> futures = someExecutorService.invokeAll(doInParallel);
for (Future<Set<String>> f : futures) {
  theResultingSet.addAll(f.get());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
// NB - Be sure to use a concurrent form of Set here.
Set set = new HashSet();
ArrayList<Map> maps = new ArrayList<>();

public void test() {
  for (final Map map : maps) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        set.addAll(map.keySet());
      }
    }).start();
  }
}
```

I realise you are not interested in the implementation of a `HashSet` that is concurrent but for completeness I would like to mention the options.

You could consider a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` if your objects implement `Comparable`, alternatively a `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object,Boolean>())` would do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better practice to use an `ExecutorService` rather than managing the threads yourself?

Comment: You beat me to it, but see my answer.  Another advantage of ExecutorService is that you don't need a concurrent Set.  (Depends on details)

Answer (score 0):

That way it would not be concurrently, but at least threadsafe:

```
Set set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
...
// in some other threads:
for (Map map : maps) {
  set.addAll(map.keySet());
}
```

Or do you prefer something like the following:

```
ConcurrentMap<Object, Boolean> set = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Boolean>();
...
// in some other threads:
for (Map map : maps) {
  for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
    set.putIfAbsent(o, true);
  }
}
```